# CSS3 link color fade on hover for visited links doesn't work

Tags: html, css, fade, css-transitions

```
.video-title a, a:link, a:visited {color: #eaeaea;
               text-decoration: none;
               font-weight: bold;
               font-size: 1.1em;
               -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;  /* Saf3.2+, Chrome */
               -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;  /* FF4+ */
               -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;  /* IE10? */
               -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;  /* Opera 10.5+ */
               transition: all 0.3s ease-in;

}
.video-title a:hover{color:#fff;
}
```

CSS looks like above example. "Color fade effect" works for all links but visited. For visited links it simply changes color to white like the way it was before, transition totally doesn't work. How to fix this problem?

Comment: I don't know about you but it works on Chrome http://tinkerbin.com/P9H32eYa

Comment: @fabianhjr join chatroom please http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5829/css3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it does work, however your site has a subtle change.

It does work quite fine.